# Searching via VLOOKUP where the search word is smaller than the searched field

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 tables. The first contains the text stings which I wish to search through (Column A), when found the a value shold be put into (Column B).  The second table contains a list of words which I want to search for in the first table (Column H) and when found supplies the result value (Column I) which will be use to populate column B. 
Column D shows the result that I require.

A   B       D           H   I
Text      Results       Required Result     Search Words    Return Type

A   B       D           H   I
Text    Results     Required        Search  Return 
            Result          Words   Type

hello   6       6           bye 1
ciao    2       2           ciao    2
bye bye #N/A        1           dog 3
st dog  #N/A        3           green   4
nd dog  #N/A        3           Green   5
tree    #N/A        #NA         Hello   6
ciao    2       2           yellow  7
ciao dog#N/A        4, 2 or #NA
t hello #N/A        6

Column B is currently populated with “=VLOOKUP(A14;H$2:I$9;2;FALSE)” a change to True brings up too may wild errors.
Changing the look up to =VLOOKUP("asteric" & A14 & "asteric";H$2:I$9;2;FALSE) unfortunately has the wildcard in the wrong section. What I need is effectively the opposite of this where the wild cards are in column H.
I know that with SQL this search would take 10 minutes to do, with excel I have tried various options but none have worked.

Can anyone please help me?

Many Thanks,

Ramiro

Comment: Please format your question, it is hard to guess how your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(H$2:H$9,A14),I$2:I$9)`

That searches for each value in H2:H9 within A14, for a match the corresponding value from I2:I9 is returned. If there are multiple matches you get the **last** one

Comment: Wow!!!
Thanks Barry.
I have been trying to figure this one out for a number of years, but all my solutions only half worked and were hugely complex.
What does the 2^15 do? 
Thanks again,
Ramiro

Comment: Thanks - can you accept my answer? You need a lookup value that will be > than any number SEARCH can return, possibly 100 or 1000 will be OK depending on your data but 2^15 [=32768] will always work because the max number of characters in a cell is 32767, hence the max number SEARCH can return